# Xcode UILocalNotification is only scheduled with time?

Tags: ios, xcode, uilocalnotification

I saw all of the properties of `UILocalNotification` is related with time, so it seems we only can set a `UILocalNotification` with a specific time.

But how can we set a `UILocalNotification` with a specific event?

For example, there is a function is running, and if there is some condition coming into existence, then `UILocalNotification` will be showed.

Comment: What have you done so far? Show us some code please.

Comment: If you want to present a local notification with the trigger of an event then I would suggest you the following function of LocalNotifications

presentLocalNotificationNow:

Presents a local notification immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you want to display a notification, do this:

```
    UILocalNotification *notification = [UILocalNotification new];
    notification.alertBody = @"some message here.";
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];
```

Note: this will only show a notification when the app is in the background.

Comment: According your Note, I think I only can bind a UILocalNotification with specific time, because the application is not running.
If I want to bind  a UILocalNotification with a specific event, I need to use UIRemoteNotification.

Thank your.

Comment: Your question did state that there is a "function running" and so I presumed you meant you were running in the background - if the app isn't running in the background this wasn't really clear. If you want to display notification while the app isn't running then yes you are going to need to use Push Notifications.

Comment: If only I implement function :


- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {



}



in class AppDelegate, I always receive LocalNotification, even I did not addLocalNotification in my app. Do you know the reason ?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "did not addLocalNotification in my app"?